# Replace <p>-tag in the_excerpt

Tags: tags, html, excerpt

I want to replace the

-tag around the_excerpt.

Right now html-output looks like this:
`<p> ...content of the excerpt... </p>`

I want to achieve this:
`<h2> ...content of the excerpt... </h2>`

I tried to use the following code in the `content-page.php` but it does not change anything.

```
<?php the_excerpt( '<h2>', '</h2>' ); ?>
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this:

```
function replace_tag($string){
    $search = array('<p>', '</p>');
    $replace = array('<h2>', '</h2>');
    echo str_replace($search, $replace, $string);
    return $string;
}
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'replace_tag');
```

or this:

```
function replace_tag($string){
    $replace = array(
        '<p>' => '<h2>',
        '</p>' => '</h2>'
    );
    $string = str_replace(array_keys($replace), $replace, $string);
    return $string;
}
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'replace_tag');
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The second solution worked perfectly... the first one causes the excerpt to appear twice.

Comment: Oh... I just saw it changes the tags in every instance the_excerpt() is used on the website. Can I limit it to be only used on a specific page template? I don't want to use it in the loop on the front page for example.

Comment: yes, you can use is_page_template()  or get_page_template_slug to limit a specific template in an if statement

Comment: Can you tell me how to limit the use of the filter for content-single.php, please?